# Primefaces and jQuery blockui plugin css conflict

Tags: jquery-plugins, primefaces, jquery-blockui

I am using Primefaces 3.5 and jQuery BlockUI plugin. In my code I am only using jQuery blockui plugin and it is working as expected. The problem I am seeing is that the css I specify for the block() method is not applied to the blocking dialog. I can modify the message but not the css. Once I specify the css for the default setting '$.blockUI.defaults={ css:{...}}', the displayed dialog moves to the top left corner of the page and still no css applied.

I tried specifying the css as close as I can to the blocking code line(that is when I invoke block()) but still no success. Any idea why this is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the blockUI css like this:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.css = { ... };
```